Which Probability Distributions Dominate the Lebesgue Measure?
Recall
In probability theory, the distribution $\mu_X$ of a random variable $X$ (on some unspoken probability space) refers to the measure $\mu_X(A) := \mathbb{P}(X \in A)$ that is defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$. On the other hand, we also have the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $\mathbb{R}$.
Random variables whose distribution $\mu_X$ satisfies $\mu_X \ll \lambda$ (defined to mean that $\lambda(A)=0\implies\mu_X(A)=0$) are widely studied. These are the so-called "continuous" distributions: those given by a density function $\mathbb{P}(X \in A) = \int_A f_X(x) \mathrm{d}\lambda(x)$.
And, now, My Question

What about random variables whose distribution satisfies the opposite relation $\lambda \ll \mu_X$? Is there a name for such distributions? Are any of their properties known?

A Few Thoughts
I can think of one property. Such distributions cannot be discrete, for then a non-empty open set outside their support would have zero $\mu_X$-measure, but positive Lebesgue-measure.
I can also think of an easy example. If $\mu_X$ is given by any continuous and strictly positive density function, then $\lambda\ll\mu_X$. Indeed, suppose $0 = \int_A f(x) \mathrm{d}\lambda(x)$. In the case that $A$ is bounded, we have $f(x)\geq\kappa>0$ on $A$, so $0 = \int_A f(x) \mathrm{d}\lambda(x) \geq \kappa \int_A 1 \mathrm{d}\lambda(x) = \kappa\lambda(A)$, implying $\lambda(A)=0$. More generally, though, if $A$ is unbounded, we can still write it as a disjoint countable union $A = \bigsqcup_nA_n$ of bounded sets and apply the same argument to $A_n$ instead of $A$.
This question occurs to me because I read a paper recently in which seemingly very similar property of log-concave distributions was utilized. Thanks for your help!

Answer: all absolutely continuous probabilities with density $f$ such that $\{x; f(x)=0\}$ has Lebesgue measure zero.
